# Javascript convert unicode string to "Title Case"

Tags: javascript, unicode, turkish, pascalcasing, title-case

I have a javascript case conversion problem which I cannot solve due to non-English letters. My main concern is the Turkish alphabet.

What I need to do is this:

- hello world => Hello World
- HELLO WORLD => Hello World
- hELLO wOrLd => Hello World

Here is what I've accomplished so far:

```
String.prototype.turkishToUpper = function(){
    var stringlow = this;
    var letterslow = { 'i': 'İ', 'ş': 'Ş', 'ğ': 'Ğ', 'ü': 'Ü', 'ö': 'Ö', 'ç': 'Ç', 'ı': 'I' };
    stringlow = stringlow.replace(/(([iışğüçö]))/g, function(letterlow){ return letterslow[letterlow]; })
    return stringlow.toUpperCase();
}

String.prototype.turkishToLower = function(){
    var stringup = this;
    var lettersup = { 'İ': 'i', 'I': 'ı', 'Ş': 'ş', 'Ğ': 'ğ', 'Ü': 'ü', 'Ö': 'ö', 'Ç': 'ç' };
    stringup = stringup.replace(/(([İIŞĞÜÇÖ]))/g, function(letterup){ return lettersup[letterup]; })
    return stringup.toLowerCase();
}

String.prototype.toProperCase = function () {
    return this.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).turkishToUpper() + txt.substr(1).turkishToLower();});
};
```

But this does not give me the correct results and I am suspecting the regex replace not being usable on unicode, but ascii.

When I test with Turkish characters, I get wrong results.

- şeker becomes **şEker** instead of **Şeker**
- çoban ırmak becomes **çOban ıRmak** intead of **Çoban Irmak**

Also, if this can ever get resolved, I need an icing on the cake to separate words not only by spaces, but also by some other stop characters such as : - = / etc so that

- hello-world becomes Hello-World
- hello:world becomes Hello:World

I've read through many similar questions here on SO, but no luck so far.

Thanks

*Note: I think this is called Title Case but some have argued that it is Pascal Case. To be frank, I am interested in resolving the unicode issue (which I believe is the root cause) rather than semantics, so please forgive me if I've used wrong terminology :)*

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this? http://jsfiddle.net/3jg3b/ - [text-transform: capitalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-transform)

Comment: Your problem with regexp selector. \S means not whitespace char but javascript identifies ş,ç as a whitespace. Take a look http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-regex-and-unicode

Comment: I'm not usind CSS @Andreas because this is for correcting formatting errors on user input.

Comment: yes @hkutluay I am aware of the fact, hense the unicode hint on the topic ;)

Comment: Does it have to work only with Turkish, or with other languages too?

Comment: Hi @hippietrail in my case Turkish is fine, but actually the solution below seems to do the job with most (if not all) accented characters. The only major problem is the Turkish "i" which is a major non-standard issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standalone function:

```
function toProperCase(s){
    return s.replace(/([^\s:\-])([^\s:\-]*)/g,function($0,$1,$2){
        return $1.toUpperCase()+$2.toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Or for extending of String.prototype:

```
String.prototype.toProperCase=function() {
    return this.replace(/([^\s:\-])([^\s:\-]*)/g,function($0,$1,$2){
        return $1.toUpperCase()+$2.toLowerCase();
    });
}

"çoban ırmak becomes çOban ıRmak intead of Çoban Irmak Hello-wOrld".toProperCase();
// "Çoban Irmak Becomes Çoban Irmak Intead Of Çoban Irmak Hello-World"
```

**Update:**

Next code uses custom functionality for converting locale specific chars (tested partially). Code adds functions into `String.prototype`: `toLocaleProperCase2`, `toLocaleLowerCase2` and `toLocaleUpperCase2`.

```
(function(){
    // locale specific chars
    // IMPORTANT: name of locale must be always in lower case (for "tr-TR" locale - "tr-tr") !!!
    var localeInfos={
            "tr-tr": { lower: { i:"İ", ı:"I", ş:"Ş", ğ:"Ğ", ü:"Ü", ç:"Ç", ö:"Ö" },
                       upper: { İ:"i", I:"ı", Ş:"ş", Ğ:"ğ", Ü:"ü", Ç:"ç", Ö:"ö" } }
        },
        localeInfo;
    // helper vars
    var mask="\\s:\\-", // add additional delimeters chars to the mask if needed
        rg=new RegExp("([^"+mask+"])([^"+mask+"]*)","g");
    var fnToLocaleLower=function(s){ return localeInfo.upper[s]; },
        fnToLocaleUpper=function(s){ return localeInfo.lower[s]; },
        fnToProper=function($0,$1,$2){
            if(localeInfo){
                if(localeInfo.lower.hasOwnProperty($1))$1=localeInfo.lower[$1];
                $2=$2.replace(localeInfo.upperSearchRegExp,fnToLocaleLower);
            }
            return $1.toUpperCase()+$2.toLowerCase();
        };
    // helper calculations
    var localeInfosKeys=Object.keys(localeInfos);
    for(var i=0;localeInfo=localeInfos[localeInfosKeys[i]];i++){
        localeInfo.lowerSearchRegExp=new RegExp("["+Object.keys(localeInfo.lower).join("")+"]","g");
        localeInfo.upperSearchRegExp=new RegExp("["+Object.keys(localeInfo.upper).join("")+"]","g");
    }

    // extending String.prototype
    String.prototype.toLocaleProperCase2=function toLocaleProperCase2(locale){
        localeInfo=localeInfos[arguments.length?locale.toLowerCase():null];
        return this.replace(rg,fnToProper);
    };
    String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase2=function toLocaleLowerCase2(locale){
        return ((localeInfo=localeInfos[arguments.length?locale.toLowerCase():null]) ?
                this.replace(localeInfo.upperSearchRegExp,fnToLocaleLower):
                this).toLowerCase();
    };
    String.prototype.toLocaleUpperCase2=function toLocaleUpperCase2(locale){
        return ((localeInfo=localeInfos[arguments.length?locale.toLowerCase():null]) ?
                this.replace(localeInfo.lowerSearchRegExp,fnToLocaleUpper) :
                this).toUpperCase();
    };
})();
```

---

```
// testing
var sss="çoban ırmak ibecıoimes çOban ıRmak intead of Çoban IrImaİk Hello-wOrld";
console.log("Origin:    ", sss);
console.log("Proper TR: ", sss.toLocaleProperCase2("tr-TR"));
console.log("Proper:    ", sss.toLocaleProperCase2());
console.log("Lower TR:  ", sss.toLocaleLowerCase2("tr-TR"));
console.log("Lower:     ", sss.toLocaleLowerCase2());
console.log("Upper TR:  ", sss.toLocaleUpperCase2("tr-TR"));
console.log("Upper:     ", sss.toLocaleUpperCase2());

// Origin:    çoban ırmak ibecıoimes çOban ıRmak intead of Çoban IrImaİk Hello-wOrld
// Proper TR: Çoban Irmak İbecıoimes Çoban Irmak İntead Of Çoban Irımaik Hello-World
// Proper:    Çoban Irmak Ibecıoimes Çoban Irmak Intead Of Çoban Irimaik Hello-World
// Lower TR:  çoban ırmak ibecıoimes çoban ırmak intead of çoban ırımaik hello-world
// Lower:     çoban ırmak ibecıoimes çoban ırmak intead of çoban irimaik hello-world
// Upper TR:  ÇOBAN IRMAK İBECIOİMES ÇOBAN IRMAK İNTEAD OF ÇOBAN IRIMAİK HELLO-WORLD
// Upper:     ÇOBAN IRMAK IBECIOIMES ÇOBAN IRMAK INTEAD OF ÇOBAN IRIMAİK HELLO-WORLD
```

Comment: Thanks @andrew-d this is almost perfect with the exception that Turkish letter "i" is off-the-charts-non-standard. Caps for "i" is "İ" and small for "I" is "ı". How do I introduce this in the equation?

Comment: @andrew: Are you saying this code does convert `ırmak` to `Irmak`? @Serkan: Are you saying it doesn't but accepting it anyway? (I'm confused.)

Comment: This much improves on the first answer which I've accepted anyway since it was 99% perfect :) And this last update seems to do the whole trick, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this useful tips. Adamsın adam

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS function that will do the job.

```
function toProperCase(string) {   
    output = '';
    explodedString = string.split(' '); //explode string by space
    for(var i=0;i<explodedString.length;i++){
        output += explodedString[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + explodedString[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()+' ';
    }
    return output.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for (... in ...)` for arrays. [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.toProperCase = function (){
   var arr= this.toLowerCase().split(' ');
   for( var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      arr[i] = arr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substr(1);
   };
   return arr.join(' ');
};

'çoban ırmak'.toProperCase() // "Çoban Irmak"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option but with the icing on the cake:

```
function toProperCase( str ) {

    var i,
        j,
        chars,
        arr;

    arr = str.toLowerCase( ).split("");

    chars = {
        " " : true,
        "-" : true,
        ":" : true,
        "=" : true,
        "/" : true
    };

    for( var i = 0, j = -1; i < arr.length; i += 1, j += 1 ) {
        // if previous char (j) exists in chars and current (i) does not;
        // replace with uppercase equivalent.
        if ( ( arr[j] && chars[ arr[j] ] && !chars[ arr[i] ] ) || i === 0){
            arr[i] = arr[i].toUpperCase( );
        }
    }

    return arr.join("");
}
```

Hopefully that helps :)