# javascript reg ex selecting every except first letter of each word (Latin extended characters)

Tags: javascript, regex

My task is to select every except first letter of each word and convert to lowercase. I've found few similar topics except one simple difference. My characters are Latin Extended and none of those expressions works for me.

Text example:

```
Kazlų RŪDA, ŽIEŽMARIŲ raj.
```

And I need such result:

```
Kazlų Rūda, Žiežmarių raj.
```

The best i came up:

```
/\B[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]/g
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript convert unicode string to "Title Case"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933577/javascript-convert-unicode-string-to-title-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way

```
var str = "Kazlų RŪDA, ŽIEŽMARIŲ raj.";
str = str.replace( /(^\S|\s\S)(\S+)/g , function(m,p1,p2){ return p1+p2.toLowerCase(); } );
// output: "Kazlų Rūda, Žiežmarių raj."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern is good, just use `String.replace` function with a callback to convert all needed characters to lowercase:

```
var str = 'Kazlų RŪDA, ŽIEŽMARIŲ raj';
str = str.replace(/[\u00C0-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+/g, (m) => m[0] + m.substr(1).toLowerCase());

console.log(str);  // "Kazlų Rūda, Žiežmarių raj"
```